# Need help using nth-of-type and first-of-type

Tags: html, css-selectors

i'm doing a exercise for my school using css like nth-of-type. i am not allowed to change the given Html code but i can't figure this out. im trying to get de first "news" class in the middle above the other 3. can someone please help me out. This is How far is have gotten.

I think im supposed to use Nth-of-type and first-of-type because i had to make a cupple exercises

```css
  .navbar {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    
    color:black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
   
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 250px;
    justify-content: space-around;
   align-content:space-around;
  
  }

  .content { background:tan;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;  
  }

  .news:nth-of-type(2),
  .news:nth-of-type(3),
  .news:nth-of-type(4) {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

  
 .news:first-of-type{
   flex-direction: column;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: center;

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <p>Home</p>
        <p>Our games</p>
        <p>Contact</p>
        <p>Support</p>
        <p>Log In</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="news">
            <h1>Gaming Website</h1>
            <p>
                Welcome to our website! We have a wild variety of games that you will probably like.
                Feel free to make a suggestion if you'd like to have another game added.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="news">
            <h3>Steam Support is now live</h3>
            <p>
                From now on, you can also start up games from your Steam library!
                The developers have worked hard for this functionality.
                If you have any bugs, report them at the Support page.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="news">
            <h3>Minecraft Steve confirmed for Smash?</h3>
            <p>
                Is Steve coming to Smash Ultimate?
                We have the latest hints and potential leaks to keep you
                updated about the possibility of the iconic tree-puncher
                coming to Smash Ultimate.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="breaking" class="news">
            <h3>Half-Life 3 confirmed</h3>
            <p>
                It is finally real. Since 1998, fans across the globe have been
                hoping for a conclusion to the Half-Life trilogy that was started
                ages ago.
                However, it was last Tuesday when it was announced that the game
                will be published next summer.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're approach is based on flex boxes but you might consider use a grid layout instead. Because it is a scool exercise I do not want to give you an exact solution here, you can find a very good introduction into css3 grids [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

In your case I think a 2x3 grid (2 rows and 3 columns) should be sufficient. You can then expand the first news div over the first row and give the remaining 3 news divs the 3 cells in the second row:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a great tool for figuring out the right nth-selector

Check this out http://nth-test.com/

But your nth-selector isn't so difficult

You want the first element with class `.news`?

```
.news:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

or if you need nth-of-type

```
.news:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: the index of nth-of-type is not zero based. Hence, use .news:nth-of-type(1) instead of .news:nth-of-type(0) to get the first element.